# Collection2, insert using method, exception from unique constraint not caught

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I create a new project:

```
$ mrt create sandbox
$ mrt remove autopublish
$ mrt add collection2
```

And use the following code to create a simple collection with a unique constraint on a key

```
SandBoxCollection = new Meteor.Collection('sandboxcoll', {
  schema: new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
      type: String,
      min: 3,
      unique: true,
      index: true
    }
  })
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('sandboxpub', function() {
    return SandBoxCollection.find();
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('sandboxpub');
}

Meteor.methods({
  create: function(doc) {
    var docId = SandBoxCollection.insert(doc, {validationContext: 'create'}, function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(333, SandBoxCollection.simpleSchema().namedContext('create').invalidKeys());
      }
      return res;
    });
    return docId;
  }
});
```

I set up a simple collection, pub/sub and a method that I can use for inserts.

Then I use the browser console to issue the following commands

Let's first create a document:

```
Meteor.call('create', {title: 'abcd01'}, function(e,r){
  console.log(e ? e : r);
});
```

Now  let's try inserting a duplicate directly using collection.insert():

```
SandBoxCollection.insert({title: 'abcd01'}, function(e,r) {
  console.log('error: ');
  console.log(e);
  console.log('errorkeys: ');
  console.log(SandBoxCollection.simpleSchema().namedContext().invalidKeys()); 
  console.log('result: ');
  console.log(r);  
});
```

We can see a proper 333 error handled by the callback and logged to the console.

Now try inserting a duplicate using the method:

```
Meteor.call('create', {title: 'abcd01'}, function(e,r){
  console.log(e ? e : r);
});
```

Notice that, unlike the direct insert, the method  throws an uncaught exception! Furthermore, the error is thrown from our custom throw and it has error code 333.

Why is this not handled properly? What can I do to mitigate this so that I can do something with the error (notify the user, redirect to the original documents page etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of February 2014, this is an enhancement request on collection2 issue tracker at https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/issues/59

The current workaround (on the server) is to catch the error separately and feed it into a custom Meteor.Error as in:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    insertDocument: function(collection, document) {
      check(collection, String);
      check(document, Object);

      var documentId = '',
          invalidKeys = [];

      function doInsert() {
        documentId = SandboxProject.Collections[collection + 'Collection'].insert(document, {validationContext: collection + 'Context'});
      }

      try {
        doInsert();
      } catch (error) {
        invalidKeys = SandboxProject.Collections[collection + 'Collection'].simpleSchema().namedContext(collection + 'Context').invalidKeys();
        error.invalidKeys = invalidKeys;
        throw new Meteor.Error(333, error);
      }
      return documentId;
    }
  });
}
```

Note: This is a generic insert method that takes the namespaced collection name as a parameter and a document. It is intended to be called from the client side with a callback function which returns either the result as a document id or an error object.

Comment: Is the ID of the object also returned when doing and `update`?

Comment: I don't know I did not check that. Why do you need the id? In fact, don't you already know the id since you are doing the updating by id?

Comment: I checked it's not, only the number of affected documents is returned, and yes. I guess you would already have the ID since you are specifying it for the update.